# Reformatting column width when using pandas dataframe.to_html()

Tags: html, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to display as a table in an html template.  It works for the most part, but some of the strings in the dataframe are being truncated.  I am using `to_html()` to convert my pandas dataframe to an html friendly table and tried using the `col_space` argument but it didn't seem to have any affect.

**The python code**:

```
options = dbi.getDBTables()  #returns a list of the names of available tables

table_headers = []

for table_name in options:
    table_name = str(table_name)
    df = dbi.selectDF("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 1" % table_name)  #gets the actual dataframe for each table name
    header = df.columns.values
    header = "<br>".join(header)
    table_headers.append(header)

header_dict = dict(zip(options,table_headers))
table_options = pandas.DataFrame(header_dict,index=[0])
table_options = table_options.to_html(classes=["table table-hover"],index=False,escape=False,col_space=400)  #changing the col_space does nothing.
search_dict = {'table_names':table_options}
```

**The html code**:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   {{ table_names | safe }}
</div>
```

**Picture of table with truncation occurring**:
[image]

How do you get pandas to stop truncating (shown as '...' in picture) content?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just needed to set `pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth',100)`